Does Power Automate support human interactions in Cloud flows?
I am getting to know Power Automate Cloud Flows and need to solve the issue that my flows are not deterministic but may require back and forth interactions with users.
As of now I use SAP Signavio Process Governance for my flows, which allows to implement human tasks as a step, assign user to them and during runtime present the user with a form containing of e.g. dynamically created text and a couple of fields to input text or make choices. The user will receive an Email with a link to the task in the Signavio system once the flow reaches the task step.
With Power Automate I have not seen a build-in equivalent. What I know of:

I can send emails, but the flow continues right away
I can create an adaptive card and make Power Automate wait for the user response, but I can send that card only via Microsoft Teams, not via Email
I can use approval workflows, but the default actions in the mail will be limited to Approve / Decline buttons
I could try to build some generic Power Apps front end and split my Power Automate Flow into two flows. Thereby the first flow ends by sending a mail to a user with a link to the Power Apps form that pulls the relevant data from a data source like SharePoint. Upon finishing work on the form the user triggers a second Power Automate flow for further processing. But having maybe 5 human tasks in a flow this will become an ugly Power Automate flow architecture.

What is considered best practice with regards to this?
Thanks a lot and most kind regards

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/
That might help you with your email desires.

This does not seem to help my case as actionable messages do not pause a flow and wait for the user response. The action in the message might only trigger a second flow, thus increasing the solutions architecture by a lot.

You gotta do what you gotta do though. Decoupling certain components can be a great way to do it. Up to you anyway.
